# select rows to read pyspark dataframe based on a latest date value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table like as shown below since the order numbers reoccur based on a date i would like to read just one of them with the latest date. example is just get A1 for 24/03/2022 on pyspark
thanks

[image: This my data table]

Answer (score 3):

w = Window.partitionBy('order').orderBy('date')

df = (df
.withColumn('rank',F.row_number().over(w)))

df = (df
.filter(df['rank'] == 1).drop('rank'))

I solved this by ranking the Orders by  date and selecting the one with the lowest rank 1